# Need MapMyIndia Documentation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, maps, swift4, mapmyindia-api

I have gone through MapmyIndia documentation, i found that they give support to Objective-C, but there were no documentation found for Swift.

Does they provide support for Swift. 
Can i get documents for Swift.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to import the framework, refer [Import Objective-c framework into Swift framework project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797212/import-objective-c-framework-into-swift-framework-project).

If you want their objective-c sample code to convert to Swift, go to https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/

Comment: but what about the documentation??